# Nullpointerexception in arrayadapter after making fragments dynamic

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments

I wanted to make my fragments dynamic so I can replace fragments for refreshing purposes.
But now that I made it I get nullpointerexception in my application.

Here is the error:

```
11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304): java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.ListEventAdapter.<init>(ListEventAdapter.java:23)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.EventFragment.parseEventFromFQLResponse(EventFragment.java:154)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.EventFragment$2.onCompleted(EventFragment.java:119)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1669)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    11-24 13:00:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31304):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is a part of my mainactivity where I start my fragment:

```
if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                Fragment newFragment = new EventFragment();
               FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

               // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
               // and add the transaction to the back stack
               transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

               // Commit the transaction
               transaction.commit();
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                Fragment newFragment = new LoginFragment();
               FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

               // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
               // and add the transaction to the back stack
               transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

               // Commit the transaction
               transaction.commit();
            }
```

The fragment_countainer is in my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is my EventFragment:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment  {

    //Arraylist with event details
    private static List<EventDetails> dataEvent;

    //Adapter to put event details in listview
    ListEventAdapter eventAdapter;

    //Listview with the events
    ListView lvEvents;

    //To show Progress Circle
    LinearLayout linearProgress;

    private static final String TAG = "EventFragment";

    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, 
                container, false);
        linearProgress = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linProgress);
        lvEvents = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvEvent);
        // Check for an open session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data
            ShowEventsFromFQL();

        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    public void ShowEventsFromFQL(){
         // Check for an open session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {

            //Progressbar active        
            linearProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            // Get the user's data
            // ORDER BY attending_count DESC
            String fqlQuery = ".....";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
            Session session2 = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request request = new Request(session2,
                "/fql",                         
                params,                         
                HttpMethod.GET,                 
                new Request.Callback(){         
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());
                        parseEventFromFQLResponse(response);                                                
                    }                  
            }); 
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }         
    }

    public final void parseEventFromFQLResponse( Response response )
    {
        dataEvent = new ArrayList<EventDetails>();
        try
        {
            GraphObject graphObj  = response.getGraphObject();
            JSONObject  jsonObj = graphObj.getInnerJSONObject();
            JSONArray   jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray( "data" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < ( jsonArr.length() ); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject jObject = jsonArr.getJSONObject( i );

                  int attending_count = jObject.getInt("attending_count");
                  String name = jObject.getString("name");
                  String host = jObject.getString("host");
                  String description = jObject.getString("description");
                  String location = jObject.getString("location");        
                  String start_time = jObject.getString("start_time");   
                  String end_time = jObject.getString("end_time"); 


                  dataEvent.add(new EventDetails(attending_count, name, host, description, location, start_time, end_time));


            }
        // if(dataEvent != null){

             eventAdapter = new ListEventAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.event_item, dataEvent);

             lvEvents.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
             eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //Progressbar gone
             linearProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         //  }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data.
            ShowEventsFromFQL();

        }
    }

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

Here is my EventFragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/spinnerProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center">
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvEvent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ListEventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EventDetails> {

    public ListEventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<EventDetails> eItems;

    public ListEventAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<EventDetails> eItems) {

        super(context, resource, eItems);

        this.eItems = eItems;
            }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        TextView txtAttending_count = null;
        TextView txtName = null;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.event_item, null);            
        }

        txtAttending_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.attending_count);
        txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

        EventDetails p = eItems.get(position);

        if (p != null) {

            if (txtAttending_count != null) {
                txtAttending_count.setText(""+p.getAttending_count());
            }
            if (txtName != null) {

                txtName.setText(""+p.getName());
            }
        }
        return v;

    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me I really dont find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your adapter data to the frament when creating the fragment smth like

```
LoginFragment f = LoginFragment.newInstance(strings);

public LoginFragment() {

private final String KEY = "KEY";
private ArrayList<String> mStrings;

static public LoginFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> strings) {
   Bundle b= new Bundle();
   b.putStringArrayList(KEY, strings)
}

void onCreate(Bundle b) {
   mStrings = getArguments().getStringArrayList(KEY);
}


}
```

Then use mStrings wherever you need in the fragment

Comment: LoginFragment? Why do I have to put it in the LoginFragment? I don't understand it?